# python: multiple arithmetic operations for numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code (need to subtract sum of previous elements from current):

```
arr = np.zeros((N,M,T))
for it in xrange(T):
     sum_arr = np.zeros((M,N))
     for tt in xrange(it): sum_arr += arr[:,:,tt]
     arr[:,:,it] -= sum_arr
```

Question: Is it way to write this code in pythonic way (prefer one line)? Thx in advance.

Comment: Your indentation in the code seems to be off.  Can you please fix it?

Comment: Yes, sorry - it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get the sum to be done more efficiently at least:

```
arr = np.zeros((N, M, T))
for it in xrange(T):
    arr[:,:,it] -= np.sum(arr[:,:,:it], axis=2)
```

which is *almost* a 1-liner:

```
for it in xrange(T): arr[:,:,it] -= np.sum(arr[:,:,:it], axis=2)
```

I assume that your real data `arr` is not all zeros -- Otherwise, the sum will be an array of zeros which you then subtract from an array of zeros leaving you with ... and array of zeros (which isn't very interesting).

Comment: It works perfectly. I just forgot about np.sum, thanks for clue.